# React Router -- syntax change from version 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: react-router

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Warning: [react-router] It appears you have provided a deprecated history object to ``, please use a history provided by React Router with `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'` or `import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'`. If you are using a custom history please create it with `useRouterHistory`, see http://tiny.cc/router-usinghistory for details.
```

**QUESTION**

Can someone please show me how to implement the react-router 2.0 syntax in my code below?

**CODE**

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route =  ReactRouter.Route;
var Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;

var StorePicker = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    var name = "tim";
    return (
      <form className="store-selector">
        <div>
          <h2>Please enter a store {name}</h2>
          <input type="text" ref="storeId" required/>
          <input type="Submit"/>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={StorePicker} />
    <Route path="/store/:storeId" component={App} />
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(routes, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually read the link that the error message suggests?

```
// ReactRouter already 'require'd
var browserHistory = ReactRouter.browserHistory;
//...
<Router history={browserHistory} />
```

Comment: I read the link.  Would greatly appreciate if you can show how to do this using require.  I am not sure how to "import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'.

Comment: Yeah, you can either use the import syntax or, since you already used "require" to get react-router, you should be able to access it using ``ReactRouter.browserHistory``.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply import it by writing the following below the variables.
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'